# jQuery Absolute Positioning depending on last element in .each() loop

Tags: jquery, css

I am currently trying to make a responsive grid layout with 1-4 columns (depending on screen size).  I am using absolute positioning instead of floating because some of these elements are taller than others.  I guess you can say this is a bit like pinterest, but the columns are not fixed width and each box has a 3.5:2 ratio or a 3.5:4 ratio which means each box's height may be different.

I have gotten as far as to lay out the columns and the box sizing works correctly, my next problem that I can't seem to figure out is to be able to position each box under the last.

I have a few each loops and here is the one that I will need to do the work in.

```
for(i=0; i<= col; i++){
    $('.card:nth-child(' + col + 'n+' + i + ')').each(function(col){ 
        $(this).css({left: (cardW + cardM)*(i-1) + "px"}).html(i);
    });
}
```

So, what this does is, depending on the number of columns, find every `nth-child` and position them horizontally with `left`.

This is working perfectly fine.  The problem is, all of the elements (being `position:absolute;`) are stuck to the top of the screen.

Now, I need to iterate through each of **those specific elements** and then **add the height of the element before it**.

I've tried indexing each element and I don't want to add classes to anything.  You can see an example **[HERE](http://beta2.mybattlereport.com/collective.php)** but nothing is currently working.

I've added this in the code:

```
var index = $(this).length;
console.log(index);
```

and I get `1` for every time, instead of something like `5`

When I index all of the elements in that each loop, I only get `1` as the index number and I don't know how to find the height of the last element.

Please comment if this doesn't make sense.

### **UPDATE**

I've got it figured out and worked the math.  Here's an addition to the code thanks to learning how to use the index number from the answer below.

```
for(i=0; i<= col; i++){
    var nthCard = $('.card:nth-child(' + col + 'n+' + i + ')')
    nthCard.each(function(idx){
        nthCard.css({left: (cardW + cardM)*(i-1) + "px"});  

        if(idx > 0){
            var prevC = nthCard.eq(idx-1);
            var prevT = parseInt(prevC.css("top").replace("px", ""));
            var prevH = parseInt(prevC.css("height").replace("px", ""));
            var prevM = parseInt(prevC.css("margin-top").replace("px", ""));
            console.log(prevT + " " + prevH + " " + prevM + " = " + (prevT + prevH + prevM));
            nthCard.eq(idx).css({top: (prevT + prevH + prevM) + "px"});
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: When I make a variable called index and count `$(this).lenght;` I always get index = 1.  `i` is working as it should

Comment: Where you have added the code `var index = $(this).length`? can you post that code. What is this here.

Comment: INside each loop use the index.. See my answer. That will give you the index of that particular item which is zero based index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

Use `$.each`'s function argument 1st one is the index and second one the element itself (or this).

```
    for(i=0; i<= col; i++){
    $('.card:nth-child(' + col + 'n+' + i + ')').each(function(idx){
        //... SOme code
                    console.log(idx)
                    //..somecode

    }); 
}
```

Comment: I just stepped away, though I will try this tonight

Comment: @ntgCleaner ok. You want the index of each item matching the nth-child right? SO idx should work.

Comment: Well the main problem is that I need to be able to give a style to each element dependent on the last

Comment: So you can store the prev obj in a temp var and update it during each right. and use prev's css to look for the properties...

Comment: Ok, so all of the cards are being indexed correctly.  Now I'm at a loss as to how to create a variable from the index number.  Let alone from the last index number.  That's my main question above (In bold)

Comment: I got it!  using .eq(idx-1) with the idx I was able to get the previous element.  After massaging it I got it to completely work.  Thank you!